# Kotlin/Native share code project startup?

Tags: kotlin-native

So kotlin/native is a thing, share your code between platforms, keep native performance, wow, sounds great, but how does one even start with kotlin/native? I'm spending a week already on those readme files from https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native with no success, cant start project from Clion(windows10), cant run any examples, cant open few example projects etc, is there any reliable guide for working with kotlin/native?

Just look at this
https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/tree/master/samples/calculator
okay, let's say that I'm trying to open that project in android studio as described in readme, boom

[image]

'Included build 'C:\shared' does not exist.' You cant sync project, android studio cant see modules because of that so it is impossible to create app config, what shared even is, do I need that, why it is there.

[image]

When you even run 'hello world' app from clion, you actually cant build it.
Is there anyone that managed to get even something to work?

Comment: Show us what you see.

Comment: @GenoChen updated the post

Answer (score 0):

You are expected to clone the whole `https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native`, and use the whole directory, not just only use the single folder...

Answer (score 0):

You may open the Kotlin/Native project with Gradle in IntelliJ IDEA (not CLion). Samples are OK to open with the latest CLion, where you have Kotlin/Native plugin installed. Some tutorials may help - https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/ - check out the `native` section on the left

Comment: yes, trying to open that stuff in windows os. not supported yet